# angular2 ngOutletContext in property bindings

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I try to use [angular2-contextmenu](https://github.com/isaacplmann/angular2-contextmenu/). According to its documentation, this should be possible:

```
  <template contextMenuItem let-item [visible]="item.type === 'type1'" [enabled]="isMenuItemEnabled(item)" (execute)="alert('Hi, ' + $event.item.name); $event.event.preventDefault();">
    Say hi, {{item?.name}}!  <my-component [attribute]="item"></my-component>
    With access to the outside context: {{ outsideValue }}
  </template>
```

When I tried to use it, however, the item variable is availabe only in the template itself, but not in expressions like `[visible]="item==='somestring'"`.

I tried to use something like

```
<template  contextMenuItem  let-item [enabled]="item == 'service-panel'">
    {{ item == 'service-panel' }} 
</template>
```

This evaluates to false because `item` is undefined:

```
[enabled]="item == 'service-panel'"
```

But the expression `{{ item == 'service-panel' }}` evaluates to true.

the context menu has following template with consists of menu items:

```
<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="menuItem.template" 
[ngOutletContext]="{ $implicit: item }"></template>
```

and class:

```
@ContentChildren(ContextMenuItemDirective) public menuItems: QueryList<ContextMenuItemDirective>;
```

ContextMenuItemDirective has the `enabled` and `visible` input properties.

```
export class ContextMenuItemDirective {
  @Input() public enabled: boolean = true;
  @Input() public visible: boolean = true;
  //...
}
```

It seems that this makes `item` variable accessible, but not in expressions like `[enabled]="item == 'service-panel'"`.

Is this by design, and is there any way to access the `item` variable in that expression?

edit:
added [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XSUSRtpiCVphRUknbjDq?p=preview) (with a slightly other example):

if `[enabled]="isDefined(item)"` is replaced with `[enabled]="true"`, the list is changed, John is removed, so it works.

Comment: What's are you trying to accomplish? What is `[enabled]="item == 'service-panel'"` supposed to do on the `<template>` tag. Angular2 doesn't render the tempate tag, it's only used internally.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: Actually I try to use the that component, and the input parameter [enabled='...'] works without problems when having constant expressions. It seems the `[ngOutletContext]="{ $implicit: item }"` makes `item` accessible in the template, but not in that input parameter expression.

Comment: i took the following line from github project site. can you try this: "** Note: ** Make sure to use the item?.property syntax in the template rather than item.property as the item will be initially undefined."

Comment: @RavinSinghD: well in the expression `item == 'service-panel'` I guess I don't need that operator since I don't have expressions where I deference `ìtem` like `ìtem.property`

Comment: can you share plunker or jsfiddle with your problem?. its easy to understand

Comment: @RavinSinghD: added plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the documentation for my angular2-contextmenu library.  In my app, I'm actually tracking the currently selected item in the parent component and using that in the template [visible] and [enabled] properties.

Like this:

```
onContextMenu($event: MouseEvent, item: any): void {
  this.selectedItem = item;
  this.cms.show.next({ event: $event, item: item });
  $event.preventDefault();
}
```

And:

```
<template contextMenuItem let-item [enabled]="selectedItem?.name == 'John'">
  ..
</template>
```

I'll update the documentation so others aren't lead down this path.

#### Edit:

Here's another alternative.  I can accept a boolean or a function for the `enabled` and `visible` inputs.  Functions would then be evaluated with the `item` value - which would mean you don't have to keep track of the selected item in your component.

Like this:

```
// parent.component.ts
public canEnable(item: any): boolean {
  return item.type === 'type1';
}

// parent.component.html
<template contextMenuItem let-item [enabled]="canEnable">
  ..
</template>
```

Implemented in [angular2-contextmenu@0.4.0](https://github.com/isaacplmann/angular2-contextmenu/)

Comment: ok thank you, but then there is no (easy) way in angular2 to make that `item` available in these expressions as well?

Comment: None that I know of.  I'll keep thinking about it today and post back if I come up with a way.

Comment: I came up with another way of solving this.  Let me know if it does what you need and I'll work on adding it to the library.

Comment: Done in version 0.4.0